# Replicate the blue/black vs. white/gold illusion in Keynote?

Tags: keynote, color

I need to create a Keynote (6.5.2) presentation for school that contains text and no graphics, but implicit silliness is highly encouraged. As such, I was thinking of having some fun with current events and finding a way to reference [The Dress](http://www.buzzfeed.com/catesish/help-am-i-going-insane-its-definitely-blue). I was wondering, can anyone come up with a way to make that optical illusion happen in Keynote?

I'm willing to play with the slide color scheme, the colors over a progression of slides, and/or the text color. My one condition is that the text always has to be legible.

(Yes, I know [the science behind the illusion](http://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/) is that it's all about the color context, but I'm still holding out hope for a way to be able to poke fun at it via a Keynote presentation. Anyone who figures out how will earn my undying gratitude!)

Comment: Wouldn't the dress be considered a graphic? How do you make a Keynote presentation of an optical illusion without images; will you be representing the dress through "slides" of sounds?

Comment: I have slide backgrounds and I have words. I don't plan to put the dress in there. I'm asking about if there's a way to mess around with the color scheme of the presentation to create the same perceived color discrepancy that's present in the picture of the dress.